# Cypher: Hierarchical Sorting

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to Cypher. I was able to create a network of geographies (from the World to continents to countries to regions) and their population.
[image: ![Geographies and Population]

You can reproduce it with this command or check the link to the console:
http://console.neo4j.org/r/dkh90c

```
CREATE (n1:Geo {name:'World'}),
(n2:Geo {name:'EMEA'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n1),
(n4:Geo {name:'NORAM'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n1),
(n5:Geo {name:'Middle East'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n2),
(n6:Geo {name:'Africa'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n2),
(n7:Geo {name:'Europe'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n2),
(n8:Geo {name:'France'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n7),
(n9:Geo {name:'Germany'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n7),
(n10:Geo {name:'Italy'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n7),
(n11:Geo {name:'United Kingdom'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n7),
(n12:Geo {name:'England'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n11),
(n13:Geo {name:'Scotland'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n11),
(n14:Geo {name:'Wales'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n11),
(n15:Geo {name:'Northern Ireland'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n11),
(n16:Geo {name:'United Arab Emirates'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n5),
(n17:Geo {name:'South Africa'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n6),
(n18:Geo {name:'Canada'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n4),
(n19:Geo {name:'United States of America'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n4),
(n20:Geo {name:'Mexico'})-[:BELONG_TO]->(n4),

(:Population {year:'2014',amount:66.1})-[:LIVE_IN]->(n8),
(:Population {year:'2014',amount:81.2})-[:LIVE_IN]->(n9),
(:Population {year:'2013',amount:59.83})-[:LIVE_IN]->(n10),
(:Population {year:'2011',amount:53.01})-[:LIVE_IN]->(n12),
(:Population {year:'2011',amount:5.295})-[:LIVE_IN]->(n13),
(:Population {year:'2011',amount:3.063})-[:LIVE_IN]->(n14),
(:Population {year:'2011',amount:1.811})-[:LIVE_IN]->(n15),
(:Population {year:'2013',amount:9.346})-[:LIVE_IN]->(n16),
(:Population {year:'2013',amount:52.98})-[:LIVE_IN]->(n17),
(:Population {year:'2013',amount:35.16})-[:LIVE_IN]->(n18),
(:Population {year:'2014',amount:318.9})-[:LIVE_IN]->(n19),
(:Population {year:'2013',amount:122.3})-[:LIVE_IN]->(n20)
```

I am also able to calculate the total population for each geography with this command:

```
MATCH (n:Population)-[r:LIVE_IN]->(g1:Geo)-[:BELONG_TO*0..]->(g2:Geo)
RETURN g2.name AS Geography, SUM(toFloat(n.amount)) AS Population
ORDER BY Population DESC
```

However, I am not happy with the sorting of the results:
[image]

As you can see, the United States of America are inserted between EMEA and Europe. Is there a way to first sort by the 'BELONG_TO' hierarchy before displaying the results? Also, despite all my data having only up to 3 decimals, I don't understand why the SUM() command return a crazy number of decimals.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you should be able to sort by the length of the path:

```
MATCH path=(n:Population)-[r:LIVE_IN]->(g1:Geo)-[:BELONG_TO*0..]->(g2:Geo)
RETURN g2.name AS Geography, SUM(toFloat(n.amount)) AS Population
ORDER BY length(path) ASC, Population DESC
```

I think that you're getting lots of decimals because of [floating point math](http://floating-point-gui.de/).  I think you should be able to do:

```
ROUND(SUM(toFloat(n.amount)) * 1000.0) / 1000.0
```

**EDIT:**

You're right, you need to add the path length to order by it:

```
MATCH path=(n:Population)-[r:LIVE_IN]->(g1:Geo)-[:BELONG_TO*1..]->(g2:Geo)
RETURN g1.name AS Geography, SUM(toFloat(n.amount)) AS Population, length(path) AS path_length
ORDER BY length(path) ASC, Population DESC
```

And yes, you're definitely right that your path needs to end with `g2` being the world.  You can do this by matching `(g2:Geo {name: 'World'})` similar to how I suggested in the comments, or if you, in the future, will happen to have more root nodes (perhaps we'll colonize the moon or Mars!), you could do this:

```
MATCH path=(n:Population)-[r:LIVE_IN]->(g1:Geo)-[:BELONG_TO*]->(g2:Geo)
WHERE NOT((g2:Geo)-[:BELONG_TO]->())
RETURN g1.name AS Geography, SUM(toFloat(n.amount)) AS Population, length(path) AS path_length
ORDER BY length(path) ASC, Population DESC
```

That means that we only want paths where g2 doesn't belong to anything.  Otherwise `g2` can be, for example, `Europe`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @brian-underwood.  

Your query doesn't work in the console. You need the `length(path)` or the `path` in the return to be able to sort on it.  
 
So, the new query is 
    `MATCH path=(n:Population)-[r:LIVE_IN]->(g1:Geo)-[levels:BELONG_TO*0..]->(g2:Geo)
    RETURN g2.name AS Geography, SUM(toFloat(n.amount)) AS Population, length(path) AS Length
    ORDER BY Length DESC , Population DESC`  
 
The result is now showing all the different paths. For instance, I now have 'World' 3 times in the first 10 entries. So this is still not good.

Comment: I probably need to combine MAX with LENGTH. 
 
The new query is: 
    `MATCH path=(n:Population)-[r:LIVE_IN]->(g1:Geo)-[:BELONG_TO*0..]->(g2:Geo)
    RETURN g2.name AS Geography, MAX(Length(path)) AS Length, SUM(toFloat(n.amount)) AS Population
    ORDER BY Length DESC , Population DESC` 
 
Notice that I broke down United Kingdom into smaller regions.  
Therefore, length is the same as NORAM or Africa.
So this is still not the solution I'm looking for.  

Is there a way to tell Neo4j to start from the 'world' node
and sort from there?

Comment: Sure, if you throw in a `WHERE g2.name = 'World'`