# Export graph database request result to produce example

Tags: neo4j

Suppose I have requested some nodes / edge in a neo4j DB. I would like to send their content to here, to expose any problem. It there any neo4j tools which could automatically write the "CREATE" request, as in this question [Cypher: Hierarchical Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34669346/cypher-hierarchical-sorting)

Comment: What do you want to do and how does your data look like :) ?

Comment: for now, nothing. All my question is about askin question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`neo4j-shell` has a `dump` command, see http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/shell-commands.html#_dumping_the_database_or_cypher_statement_results 
It spits out the results of a cypher query as `CREATE` commands.